# Neo4j acquire/release the write lock - true/false vs remove

Tags: neo4j, cypher, transaction-isolation

In Neo4j in order to simulate the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level I need to explicitly set a dummy property, for example:

```
SET n._lock_ = true
```

But how to properly release the lock, do I need to `SET n._lock_ = false` or to completely remove it via `REMOVE n._lock_` query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the documented [default locking behavior](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.3/transactions/#transactions-locking). According to the documentation, the `write lock` is "released when the transaction finishes".

Therefore, once you set the write lock, it is not released until your Cypher query (and transaction) finishes.

The reason you want to include a `REMOVE n._lock_` clause before ending your query is so that you make sure the `_lock_` property, which is intended as a temporary hack, is no longer there after the query ends. (But the removal of that property is not responsible for the release the write lock.)

Comment: Thanks, so it is impossible to remove the lock before the transaction ends?

Comment: Using neo4j's Java API, say when you are writing a plugin procedure, you can explicitly release the write [Lock](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Lock.html) that you obtained when you [acquired the wire lock](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#acquireWriteLock-org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do.

Neo4j is transactional, so there is a transaction isolation, and Neo4j manages locks for you.

Sometimes, it is useful to manually create a lock by setting a dummy property, for example in order to avoid deadlock.

Locks are released when you commit/rollback the transaction.

Comment: AFAIK Neo4j use read-committed isolation level, with custom lock I’d like to emulate serializable isolation level. The question is how to properly remove the lock before the transaction ends